# search the limit of a sum with an integral

Tags: integration, solution-verification

I'm looking for the limit when $n\rightarrow\infty$ of the sum
$$S=\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}e^{-2h\sin\left(\frac{\pi j}{n}\right)}$$
The angle in the sine is $\theta=\frac{\pi j}{n}$ and as $j$ varies from one unit in two successive terms, ($\delta j=1$), I set $d\theta=\frac{\pi}{n}\delta j=\frac{\pi}{n}$
It seems that I can now replace the exponential in the sum by :
$\frac{1}{d\theta}e^{-2h\sin\left(\frac{\pi j}{n}\right)}d\theta=\frac{n}{\pi}e^{-2h\sin\theta}d\theta$. The sum may thus converges to the integral:

$$\frac{n}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-2h\sin\left(\theta\right)}d\theta$$

(After that the integral is accessible by a series development).
The boundaries come from the fact that for $j=1,\theta\rightarrow 0$ and for $j=\frac{n}{2}, \theta\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}$
Is that correct?

Comment: Can you please edit your question?

Comment: done. Actually there was a LaTeX bug.

Comment: Can I ask you why the sum goes from $1$ to $\frac{1}{n}$? Shouldn't it be just $1$ to $n$? Or at least $1$ to $2n$?

Comment: No, the sum goes from 1 to $\frac{n}{2}$ more explicitely from 1 to $k=n\div2$, $\div$ designing the integer quotient without reminder. For the spliting of of a circle of radius one  $2\pi$ by $n$  it represents the number of classes of distance between two points of the circle. Example: $n=5 \Rightarrow k=2$; $n=6\Rightarrowk=3$ etc.

Comment: So you want to sum from $1$ to $\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor$? (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)